# For the positively oriented circle, $\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{2\Re(z)}{z+1}dz=......$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

> For the positively oriented circle, 
>   $\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{2\Re(z)}{z+1}dz=......$
>
> (a) $0$
>
> (b) $\pi i$
>
> (c) $2\pi i$
>
> (d) $4\pi i$

$$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{2\Re(z)}{z+1}dz$$
$$=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z^2+1}{z(z+1)}dz$$  ($\because$ $z$ is in the unit circle, $\overline{z}=\frac{1}{z})$

$$=2\pi if(0)=\pi i$$

But in the book, answer is $0$. Where did I go wrong? Please help me.

Comment: In the first place this integral is **divergent** and can only be saved using some exception handling measures; see Jack D'Aurizio's answer.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter where it is divergent?

Comment: can you explain, How does the cauchy's inegral formula fail?

Comment: Cauchy theorem holds for meromorphic functions, yours isn't one of them.

Comment: meromorphic function on an open subset D of the complex plane is a function that is holomorphic on all of D except for a set of isolated points, which are poles of the function. Right? $\frac{z^2+1}{z+1}$ has pole at $z=-1$. right? Except all points it is analytic right?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio can you explain?

Comment: Re(z)/(z+1) is neither meromorphic or holomorphic in a puntured neighbourhood of -1. Cauchy formula does not apply, plain and simple, since the Cauchy-Riemann equation is not fulfilled.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ok. How did you proved? by applying C-R equation?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan: is your function expandable as a power series in $z$ around, say, $z=0$? No, Cauchy theorem does not apply.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio $\frac{z^2+1}{z+1}=(z^2+1)(1-z+z^2-z^3+...).$  for $|z|<1$. Right?. sorry for disturbing. still find problem. please help me.

Comment: Seems like analytic.

Comment: That function is analytic, but that function and $\frac{\text{Re}(z)}{z+1}$ are different functions on the complex plane.

Comment: The problem is not so much that the integrand is not meromorphic (you found a way around this) but that the curve passes through the singularity $z=-1$ of the integrand.

Comment: For instance, one fulfills $f(\overline{z})=\overline{f(z)}$, the other doesn't.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: of course, but I guess the OP forgot to mention that in the definition of $\oint$ some way of "dodging" the singularity at $z=-1$ has to be included. If we dodge it in a symmetrical fashion (the usual way), we find the Cauchy principal value.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio ok. thank you. It is clear now.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By letting $z=e^{i\theta}$ we have $dz= i e^{i\theta}d\theta$ and the wanted integral equals

$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\text{Re}(e^{i\theta})}{1+e^{i\theta}}ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta =i\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos\theta(e^{i\theta}+1)}{2+2\cos\theta}\,d\theta=i\color{blue}{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos\theta}{2}\,d\theta}-\color{red}{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin\theta\cos\theta}{2(1+\cos\theta)}\,d\theta}$$
where the blue integral equals $0$ by the periodicity of $\cos$ and red integral is, strictly speaking, undefined like $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{x}$, but its principal value equals zero since the integrand function is odd.

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Comment: $$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\text{Re}(e^{i\theta})}{1+e^{i\theta}}ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta =i\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos\theta(e^{i\theta}+1)}{2+2\cos\theta}\,d\theta=i\color{blue}{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos\theta}{2}\,d\theta}-\color{red}{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin\theta\cos\theta}{2(1+\cos\theta)}\,d\theta}$$

Comment: How does the first equality come?

Comment: $\text{Re}(e^{i\theta})=\cos\theta$, then split $e^{i\theta}+1$  as the sum between its real part and i times its imaginary part, then simplify.

Comment: $Re(e^{i\theta})=\cos\theta$, fine. how $\frac{e^{i\theta}}{1+e^{i\theta}}$ tranformed to $\frac{1+e^{i\theta}}{2+2\cos\theta}$

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan: multiply by $\frac{1+e^{-i\theta}}{1+e^{-i\theta}}=1$.

Comment: why not limits from $0$ to $2\pi $?

Comment: @TheStudent: it's the same, we are dealing with $2\pi$-periodic functions.