# Complex integration over $|z|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given integration over contour $|z|=1$ a unit circle. Evaluate the integral:

> $$\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{2 \Re z}{z+2}dz$$ where $\Re z$ is real part of $z$

$\textbf{Solution i tried}$-Here the contour is $|z|=1$ $\implies$ $z \bar{z}=1\implies \bar{z}=\frac{1}{z}$

now the above integration can be written as $$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\frac{2(z+\bar{z})}{2}}{z+2}\\\implies \oint\frac{z+\bar{z}}{z+2}$$

$$\oint \frac{z^2+1}{z(z+2)}$$

thus the only singularity in $|z|=1$ is $0$, so the integral will be $$2\pi \iota \times \frac{1}{2}=\pi \iota $$

but my answer is wrong, am I making a mistake somewhere ?

Please help

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that your evaluation is wrong?

Comment: because answer given in $0$

Comment: Compare with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512149/for-the-positively-oriented-circle-oint-z-1-frac2-rezz1dz

Comment: This is better than 2512149, since this one is not divergent.

Comment: @vitamind I disagree. Not having a pole on the path of integration makes a huge difference in my opinion.